# Cannot write to file

Tags: python

I'm trying to write each line of an existing file into two new files.
Basically this will copy the file.
The "oldMaster.write(line)" returns an error that says the file is not writable.
I know my code is terrible. This is for a project and I'm really stuck.

```
file_str = input ("Enter a file name: ")

while True:
    try:
        file_obj = open(file_str, 'r')
        break
    except IOError:
        file_str = input("'Invalid file name' Enter a file name: ")        
prefix = input("Master File Prefix?")
old = prefix
old += ".old.txt"
new = prefix
new += ".new.txt"
oldMaster = open(old,"w")
newMaster = open(new,"w")

oldMaster = file_obj
newMaster = file_obj

for line_str in file_obj:
    line = line_str

    oldMaster.write(line)
```

Comment: That code won't even run because you use an undefined variable `file_obj`.

Comment: What is `file_obj` and what is it doing there?

Comment: Can you check to see that the file was opened successfully?

Comment: @BrenBarn Sorry. Fixed

Comment: Why do you create `oldMaster` and `newMaster` and overwrite those values 2 lines later?

Comment: I still don't understand what file_obj has to do with new and old masters. What does it suppose to do?

Comment: I'm trying to make oldMaster and newMaster the same as file_obj, which is a text file

Comment: If you just want to copy the file use [shutil.copyfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not closing the file, you have to send the `commit` signal in order to write to the file.

Try using `with`, which `opens` and closes the file handle.

```
with open(old,"w") as oldMaster,open(new,"w") as newMaster:
```

Comment: How would I do it without using with?

Comment: OMG I love you. I closed the files at the end and it worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `file_obj` exists only into `while`. Try to print its value after `while`.

So then after you open file:

```
>>> oldMaster = open('\users.csv',"w")
```

look at what oldMaster equal to:

```
>>> oldMaster
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='\users.csv' mode='w' encoding='cp1251'>
```

then you ovewrite `oldMaster` with a variable `file_obj`, which has some values, but no file:

```
>>> oldMaster='smthelse'
>>> oldMaster
'smthelse'
```

So `oldMaster` contain `smthelse`, not file.

I think, you should delete `while`.